# Redirect to the another html page after clicking input tag in django template

Tags: javascript, html, django

I want to redirect the website after edit (http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/edit/) to the dashboard (http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/dashboard) in Django template. I have a file named dashboard.html in the same directory. But it keeps me to the same page (http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/edit/.

**edit.html**

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Edit your account{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Edit your account</h1>
    <p>You can edit your account using the following form:</p>
    <form action="dashboard.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save change"></p>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with js (jquery in this example):

script.js:

```
$('#button-id').click(function() {
  window.location = 'the_new_url';
});
```